# How can I deploy my application within a cloned repository on Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm using a node package to run a web server (among other benefits) for my project. The catch is, my project is only loaded on the server if it's within a directory of the node package. In other words, my directory structure looks like this:

```
<npm_pkg>/
  <npm_pkg_src>/
  clients/
    <my_project_name>/
      <my_project_src>
```

I would like to be able to use standard deployment processes for my project (e.g. `gcloud app deploy`, Travis continuous deployment, etc.), but I need to run my project from within a subdirectory of the larger package. Is there an easy way to force a `git clone <pkg>` during a build step and deploy my project in the target subdirectory?

I'm pretty new to CI/CD, but I tried to search around for similar examples and couldn't find any. Note: the parent project is *not* owned by me and thus I can't just use submodules without forking it (and I have no intention to alter it in any way). I also strictly just want to be able to trigger deploys based on my actual project's repository, if possible, whereas submodules would involve maintaining two and committing features twice (from what I understand).

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to mention that as part of this configuration I also need to run my server script from the root of the parent package. IOW, my `package.json`'s start script will look like `"start": "cd ../.. && npm start"`. Just in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you’re looking for: [CI/CD with App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-deploying-from-source-repositories-to-app-engine)

Clone from the repo and deploy from the subdirectory it is located, and [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/) can automate the whole process for you

I would also suggest you keep services separate, this will make things clearer for you and others that will/might be working on the project with you

Comment: I think that's not _quite_ what I'm looking for, but thank you for responding! I understand how to deploy a basic application in which your run the app from root directory of the git repository. But what I'm confused by is how to deploy an application that needs to be run from _within_ another repository **that is not part of the original project.** In other words, I'd like my deployment to clone (and npm install) the "other" repository first, then put **my repository's build** inside a subdirectory of the "other" repo.

Comment: I think you might have to separate your services in order to do so